# Bypass windows Aunthentication

Tags: anonymous

We have developed a `MVC` Application and it's `Windows Authentication` enabled,
(`Web.config - AuthenticationMode="Windows"`).
But we have requirement where a set of pages need to be behaved as Anonymous aunthentication.

Since a `web.config` is pointed to `Windows Authentication` , Our application is always prompting Domain user Name & Password when user access to any pages.

We have tried `CustomAuthorize` & `IAunthenticationFilter` to bypass the windows Authentication But it is still prompting the User Name and Password.

Is there any way to Implement Anonymous Authentication for few pages/Controllers while rest of the pages/controllers running in the windows Authentication Mode ?

Or 
Is there any way to feed the Domain user id and Password programatically ?